# Пагинция на основе массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Может кто сталкивался с такой задачкой, сервер мне присылает массив из 100 комментариев, и мне надо на странице отображать только первые 5 и кнопку "показать ещё" после нажатия на кнопку он отображает следующие 5 комментариев и снова кнопку "показать ещё" и так до самого конца массива.
Собственно сам вопрос, можно ли это реализовать при помощи js и jquery?
если да, то как, возможно есть какие то примеры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример реализации на коленке

```js
let data = Array(100).fill(0).map((d,i) => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2));
let count = 5;
let current = 0;
let max = Math.floor(data.length/count) - (data.length%count?0:1);

page(0);

function page(n) {
  current = Math.min(Math.max(0, current+n), max);
  let cc = current*count;
  let show = data.slice(cc, cc + count)
  document.querySelector('#count').innerHTML = `${cc+1}-${cc+count} / ${data.length}`;
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = show.map(d => `<div>${d}</div>`).join('');
}
```

```css
div#result div {
  border:1px solid; 
  margin:3px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='page(-1)'>&lt;</button>
<span id="count"></span>
<button onclick='page(+1)'>&gt;</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример похожей реализации с использованием `jquery`

https://codepen.io/simoncodrington/pen/bgPYqr